# How to block internet for other users in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, internet

Is there any way to block a user to use Internet in Windows Xp.

Suppose user A is an Administrator of windows Xp os & he wants to block user B who is just a Guest. Then how user a could do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure as being on a locked-down work computer I am fairly sure you can do this through local group policy.

Depending on guest knowledge level you could just remove the shortcuts to IE/Firefox or turn Windows Firewall on and block all ports and no execptions.

Comment: It will not work because user B can create dummy.html & can access internet.

Answer (score 0):

on Windows XP (at least professional) you can go Start --> run and type gpedit.msc to fire the Group policy editor (you need to be admin for that)

Then from there you can edit a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

In policy, select a false proxy for Guest user. If it were a PC with ISA it would be lot simple.